# How to close a confirm dialog opened by another window in GEB

Tags: testing, automated-tests, geb

In one of my functional GEB tests we have a situation where we are opening a new window by using

```
withNewWindow({ button.click() }, "close": true, "wait": true) {
   //Other things
}
```

Now when that window is being closed a confirm dialog is opening which says whether you want to leave this page or not. How to close that confirm dialog?

I know that there is a method `withConfirm` for closing confirm dialogs but I am not doing anything to open/close it but instead `withNewWindow` is opening/closing that.

I tried various options but couldn't figure out how to do that. I looked at the [docs](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.1/javascript.html) but couldn't find any examples for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass `false` for the `close` option of `withNewWindow()` and then wrap closing the newly opened window in a `withConfirm()` call in such case:

```
withNewWindow({ button.click() }, close: false, wait: true) {
    //Other things
    withConfirm { driver.close() }
}
```

Comment: Any idea about closing windows already present? Getting "org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Unexpected modal dialog (text: This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.) The alert disappeared before it could be closed.:" Actually trying to close all windows except the current one via iterating over browser.getAvailableWindows()

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. Should you post a new question?